# how to give margin between li using css?

Tags: angularjs, css, ionic-framework

]I am trying to make a breadcrumb as shown in the image below. I am able to make this thanks to some Google searching, But I have few issues:

- It is not responsive. Why? when I decrease window width breadrumb also decrease as same as header which work on all resolution .In other words when we decrease width it fontsize and width according to screen resolution
- There is a margin between two li as shown in image. I used the margin property, but it doesn't seem to be effective.

here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNPExE

```
/* Styles go here */
.breadcrumb_nav_div{
  top:44px;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  background-color:lightgrey;
  padding:0.8em 0em 0.5em 1em;
}
.breadcrumb { 
            list-style: none; 
            overflow: hidden; 
            font: 14px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
        }
        .breadcrumb li { 
            float: left; 
      margin-left:5px

        }
        .breadcrumb li a {
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none; 
            padding: 10px 0px 10px 55px;
            background: grey;                   /* fallback color */
            background: grey; 
            position: relative; 
            display: block;
            float: left;
        }
        .breadcrumb li a:after { 
            content: " "; 
            display: block; 
            width: 0; 
            height: 0;
            border-top: 50px solid transparent;           /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
            border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
            border-left: 30px solid grey;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -50px; 
            left: 100%;
            z-index: 2; 
        }   
        .breadcrumb li a:before { 
            content: " "; 
            display: block; 
            width: 0; 
            height: 0;
            border-top: 50px solid transparent;           /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
            border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
            border-left: 30px solid white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -50px; 
            margin-left: 1px;
            left: 100%;
            z-index: 1; 
        }   
        .breadcrumb li:first-child a {
            padding-left: 10px;
        }
        .breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a       { background:        grey; }
        .breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a:after { border-left-color: grey; }
        .breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a       { background: grey; }
        .breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a:after { border-left-color: grey; }
        .breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a       { background:grey; }
        .breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a:after { border-left-color: grey; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase the spacing between the icons use:

```
.breadcrumb li a:before { 
    margin-left: 5px; /* Increase this number for thicker space */
}
```

But your question is unclear as to the responsiveness. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: actually when you decrease window width it also decrease as check header

Comment: mean it will work on all screen resolution ..when I reduced size it font size reduce ..As header which is working fine in all resolution .can we make same thing in breascumb

Comment: It is not responsive. Why? when I decrease window width breadrumb also decrease as same as header which work on all resolution .In other words when we decrease width it fontsize and width according to screen resolution

Comment: Yes I get your point, to do so you need media queries for the resolutions you want, or then you create the "li" elements with "%" size, and not "px", and use "em" for the font instead of "px". But I'd recomend media queries on the CSS. Google them.

Comment: without media queries can we do this in percentage ?

Comment: No, what media queries do is change the CSS for different resolutions. So in 1920px your "li" will have 50px width, but for 360px resolution it will haev only 20px width.

Comment: ok ..I will try ...but you said that you take in % and em will work for all sceewn

Comment: No, I said that's another possible solution. Yes it works with a lot of problems also, because if you reduce the screen further and further it will be nearly invisible. Try both of them, they are both solutions to your problem, just different. See which one you need,

Comment: Thanks for answer ..I have one issue in your solution  I don't want white line on last arrow (last li element) ..I did like that http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dogVba ..breadcrumb li :nth-child a:before {
  border:1px solid red!important
       margin-left: 0px!important;

}

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNPGYe There you go, you were missing a ";" and "last-child" selector.